# Can't get or display post thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm working on wordpress posts and i'm trying to **display/get the post thumbnail**. I tried many things which are supposed to work but not for me ... here is the code :

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo ('there is a thumbnail');
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), "thumbnail"); // nothing
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); // nothing
    echo var_dump(get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), "thumbnail")); //string '' (length=0)
    echo var_dump(get_the_post_thumbnail()); //string '' (length=0)
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); // nothing
    the_post_thumbnail(); // nothing
}
else {
    echo ('there is no thumbnail');
}
```

first i thought that there were no thumbnail for my post but my first `echo` returned `there is a thumbnail` and all the rest doesn't return anything ... so i don't understand... what is missing ?

Thanks

Comment: this i functions.php right? you need to call the functions in some page or template and visit that template to get the thumbnails

Comment: i'm creating a plugin therefore i'm in my "plugin.php"... how can i proceed to stay in my plugin directory and use this function ?